# Center div on page - ignoring parent div (accordian)

Tags: css, accordion, responsive, lightbox

I need to centre the dropdown of the accordion to break out of the parent div and be full width.

As the accordion is horizontal on the page if I do a min-width the inner accordion on the right goes off the page.

I have tried all of the following but none have worked:

https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

if anyone could recommend a neat solution I would really appreciate it here is the current page:

https://businesscultureawards.com/categories/

```
.x-accordion-inner {

position: relative;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 999 !important;
border-radius: 0 0 80px 0 !important;
background-color: #D3D5D4;
min-width:500px; //on the 4th acccordion across this makes the div go off screen

}
```

So when the categories are clicked rather than staying the width of the container div I would like it to go full width of the screen.

(I have also thought about doing a lightbox but not quite got that working yet...)

Many thanks!

Comment: Please share the relevant code here that allows the problem to be reproduced. Much easier to provide an answer that way!

Comment: Looks like it would be much easier to move content to different area (between rows)